# ARKit Reference Image physicalSize issue on iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, xcode10, ios12

I'm running into an issue where an app with a deployment target of 10.0, built with iOS 12 SDK (Xcode 10.0 10A255), doesn't retain the physical sizes of my AR reference images. Because of this, the `ARSCNView` remains what appears to be uninitialized (all black).

Interestingly, there's no issue with pre-iOS 12.0 devices, nor is there an issue when I set the deployment target to 12.0. Is there any workaround for this that doesn't involve setting the deployment target to 12.0?

All images have the same physicalSize:

`- 0 : <ARReferenceImage: 0x280ff40a0 name="image_target_name" physicalSize=(0.000, 0.000)>`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with this issue, it looks like Xcode 10 is having problems correctly utilizing  reference images placed in the AR Resources directory when the deployment target is < 12.0. You can still programmatically create reference images and set their physical width.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arreferenceimage